# volttron scheduling actuator agent with CRON

Tags: volttron

For my volttron agent that I used the [agent creation wizard](https://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/develop/developing-volttron/developing-agents/agent-development.html) to develop, can I get a tip on an error related to this , `'Timezone offset does not match system offset: -18000 != 0. Please, check your config files.'`

When testing my script with the `from volttron.platform.scheduling import cron` feature I noticed the timezone/computer time was way off on my edge device so I reset the time zone with this [tutorial](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-or-change-timezone-on-ubuntu-20-04/) which I am thinking definitely screwed things up.

```
ERROR: volttron.platform.jsonrpc.RemoteError: builtins.ValueError('Timezone offset does not match system offset: -18000 != 0. Please, check your config files.')
```

Whether or not this makes a difference this edge device does use the fowarding agent to push the data to a central VOLTTRON instance.

```
2021-05-14 12:45:00,007 (actuatoragent-1.0 313466) volttron.platform.vip.agent.subsystems.rpc ERROR: unhandled exception in JSON-RPC method 'request_new_schedule':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/volttron/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/rpc.py", line 158, in method
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/volttron/.volttron/agents/8f4ee1c0-74cb-4070-8a8c-57bf9bea8a71/actuatoragent-1.0/actuator/agent.py", line 1343, in request_new_schedule
    return self._request_new_schedule(rpc_peer, task_id, priority, requests, publish_result=False)
  File "/home/volttron/.volttron/agents/8f4ee1c0-74cb-4070-8a8c-57bf9bea8a71/actuatoragent-1.0/actuator/agent.py", line 1351, in _request_new_schedule
    local_tz = get_localzone()
  File "/var/lib/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tzlocal/unix.py", line 165, in get_localzone
    _cache_tz = _get_localzone()
  File "/var/lib/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tzlocal/unix.py", line 90, in _get_localzone
    utils.assert_tz_offset(tz)
  File "/var/lib/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tzlocal/utils.py", line 46, in assert_tz_offset
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Timezone offset does not match system offset: -18000 != 0. Please, check your config files.
```

This is my raise_setpoints_up function below that is alot like the CSV driver agent code.

```
def raise_setpoints_up(self):

_log.info(f'*** [Setter Agent INFO] *** -  STARTING raise_setpoints_up function!')
schedule_request = []

# create start and end timestamps
_now = get_aware_utc_now()
str_start = format_timestamp(_now)
_end = _now + td(seconds=10)
str_end = format_timestamp(_end)

# wrap the topic and timestamps up in a list and add it to the schedules list
for device in self.jci_device_map.values():
    topic = '/'.join([self.building_topic, device])
    schedule_request.append([topic, str_start, str_end])

# send the request to the actuator
result = self.vip.rpc.call('platform.actuator', 'request_new_schedule', self.core.identity, 'my_schedule', 'HIGH', schedule_request).get(timeout=4)
_log.info(f'*** [Setter Agent INFO] *** -  actuator agent scheduled sucess!')
```

Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect the time configured by tzdata is different than the timezone configured by the system since you changed this manually.  Give this a try:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Comment: I ran the code and setup the timezone but now in my volttron log, I have an error `2021-05-14 17:55:00,047 (actuatoragent-1.0 316896) actuator.scheduler ERROR: Failed to save scheduler state!`

Comment: Any ideas to try? Thanks!

Comment: would it be worth from the root user on this edge device restarting the volttron service? something like `systemctl restart volttron`?

Comment: I just went and tried that but same error : (

Answer (score 0):

use `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` to change back to UTC time